# How to garbage-collect unused docker images?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, google-container-registry

All

use Google Computing Engine to run Monte Carlo by deploying Docker images, running them, deleting them, deploying more images, ...

If I look into disk usage of the bucket which has containers/images

> gsutils du gs://bucket

I'll get close to 6Gb of space used

But! I know that right now there is only one docker image

> gcloud container images list --repository=repo

and it should take no more than 1.5Gb.

Is there good and simple way to do garbage collection? How I could clean-up all images which are NOT used right now, and get storage usage down to something real?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Cloud Console to delete some images that might have some unused tags.

You can also use the [gcloud commands](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/managing) to list and delete them,
here an example of the commands to be run:

```
gcloud container images list-tags gcr.io/project-id/hello-node
DIGEST        TAGS    TIMESTAMP
e302a6a81293  v1      2015-01-26T15:29:27
dac925b4030f  latest  2017-12-10T15:33:41
```

Untag your unused versions

```
gcloud container images untag gcr.io/project-id/hello-node:v1
```

List your images again

```
gcloud container images list-tags gcr.io/project-id/hello-node
DIGEST        TAGS    TIMESTAMP
e302a6a81293          2015-01-26T15:29:27
dac925b4030f  latest  2017-12-10T15:33:41
```

Delete your untag image, you need to use the following format for digest: gcr.io/repository@sha256:digest

```
gcloud container images delete gcr.io/project-id/hello-node@sha256:e302a6a81293
```

So listing your images should give you now:

```
DIGEST        TAGS    TIMESTAMP
dac925b4030f  latest  2017-12-10T15:33:41
```

More info about the 'gcloud container images delete' [in here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/images/delete). You can also delete the image and the tag at the same time using flag '--force-delete-tags':

```
gcloud container images delete gcr.io/project-id/hello-node@sha256:dac925b4030f --force-delete-tags
```

Answer (score 1):

If it helps, here is little bash script which removes all matching images built before a given date: https://gist.github.com/27Bslash6/ba9dca6ca6b90c05d6bfa9136c667e9a

For example, to delete all gcr.io/things/stuff images older than 1st July 2017:

`./gcrgc.sh gcr.io/things/stuff 2017-07-01`

Includes an option to perform a trial run, listing images which would be deleted.